# GridView redrawing after clicking

Tags: android, android-layout, android-gridview

I'm changing the adapter's data and calling **adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(), gridview.invalidateViews(), gridview.setAdapter(adapter)**
But it doesn't help to redraw gridview. It is actually redrawing but only after I click on this gridview.
This gridview is a child of ViewFlipper. Any ideas how to force to redraw?

Answer (score 0):

Calling `invalidate()` on the GridView itself or the parent ViewFlipper might solve your problem.

Comment: I tried to call viewFlipper.invalidate() and gridview.invalidate(), same behavior

Answer (score 0):

I had to run invalidateViews() in UiThread

```
`runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
       ((GridView)viewFlipper.getChildAt(pageNum)).invalidateViews();
   }
});`
```